# Set variable inside for loop using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to iterate all files and get a date from each file name inside a folder `C:\data`.

Suppose we have two files inside the `data` folder

> abc_CDK_KPMG_11222018.txt
>   mgk_CDK_KPMG_10222018.txt

I wrote the script:

```
FOR /R  C:\data\ %K in (*.txt) do (
set fileName=%~nK
set fileName=%fileName:~-8%
echo.%date2%
)
```

I got the file name and date from the above script but how do I get the date from both files?

Comment: Kindly, use only the relevant tags. This doesn't seem to be related to WinForms or Powershell. Also, read the tag wiki of [windows] to understand when it's appropriate to use it.

Comment: You'll need to use `%%` instead of `%` in a batch file, and you don't need `/R` because the files are inside the directory, not buried within its subdirectories. i.e. `For %%K In ("C:\data\*.txt") Do ...`.

Comment: The batch won't work without [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for the the file date use the for meta [variable](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) %%~tK modifier. **In a batch file use doubled percent signs for the for meta variable.**

Comment: I replace %% instead of % but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to `enable` `delayedexpansion`. See `set /?` and `setlocal /?` from cmdline.

Secondly, you set `filename`, but echo `%date2%` I assume you wanted this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /R "C:\data\" %K in (*.txt) do (
 set fileName=%~nK
 set fileName=!fileName:~-8!
 echo !filename!
 )
```